# Solve the ODE $y'^{2}+y^2=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I can figure out solutions $y=\sin x$ or $\cos x$ and trivial solution $y=1$. But how to get all solutions?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Note also that the function defined by $y(x)=1$ if $x\leq 0$, $y(x)=\cos(x)$ if $x\geq 0$, is differentiable everywhere, and a solution of your equation...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

If you're looking for the solutions around $x=0$ and supposes that $\vert y(0) \vert \lt 1$ then the ODE is equivalent to

$$\frac{y^\prime(x)}{\sqrt{1 - y^2(x)}} = \pm 1$$ which can be integrated as

$$\arcsin\left(y(x) \right) = \pm x + C$$ and leads to
$$y(x) = \sin\left(\pm x +C\right).$$

While if $\vert y(0) \vert \gt 1$ there is no solution and the solution is constant when $\vert y(0) \vert =1$.

Comment: You wrote: "And if $|y(0)|≥1$ there is no solution." This is not true, since $y=1$ and $y=-1$ are solutions of the original ODE.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for noticing the typo. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I$ an interval in $ \mathbb R$ and let $y:I \to \mathbb R$ be a solution of the ODE.

Furthermore we assume that $y'(x) \ne 0$ for all $x \in I$. This gives $|y(x)|<1$ for all $x \in I.$ From $y'(x)= \pm \sqrt{1-y(x)^2}$, we see that $y'$ is differentiable on $I$ and

$$2y'(x)y''(x)+2y'(x)y(x)=0$$

for all $x \in I.$ Hence

$$ y''+y=0.$$

The last ODE has the general solution $y(x)=a \cos x+ b \sin x.$ It is now easy to see that $a^2+b^2=1.$

Conclusion:

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\pm \int dx$$
$$\implies \sin^{-1} x=\pm x+C \implies y(x)=\pm \sin (x\pm C)$$
So the general solution can also be written as $y=\pm [\sin x \cos C\pm \cos x \sin C]$ If $C=0$ Solution is $y=\pm \sin x$, if $C=\pi/2$ the solution is $y=\pm \cos x$.$y(x)=1$ is singular (essential) solution of this ODE which is free of constant.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'^2=1-y^2.$$

If $y^2=1$, we get $y'=0$ and we have two constant solutions $y=\pm1$.

Otherwise,

$$\frac{y'^2}{1-y^2}=1$$ or $$\frac{y'}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\pm1^*.$$

Then by integration,

$$\arcsin(y)-\arcsin(y_0)=\pm x$$ and

$$y=\sin(\arcsin(y_0)\pm x).$$

---

$^*$Note that we cannot switch from $+1$ to $-1$ at some arbitrary $x$, as this would introduce a discontinuity in the derivative. Hence the sign remains constant for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Failed attempt:**

As the $(y,y')$ trajectory is a circle, we can write the solution as $$y(x)=\sin(u(x)),y'(x)=\cos(u(x)).$$ This requires

$$y'(x)=\cos(u(x))=u'(x)\cos(u(x))$$ and $u'(x)=1$ or $\cos(u(x))=0$.

The first case yields $u(x)=x+c$, or $y(x)=\sin(x+c)$, and the second is $y(x)=\pm1$.

Unfortunately, this method does not yield the most general solution because it does not cover the case

$$y(x)=\cos(u(x)),y'(x)=\sin(u(x))$$ that results in $u'(x)=-1$.